# Activity Intent sometimes has null extra

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-activity, android-notifications

I'm seeing a problem where an Activity crashes grabbing an Intent extra due to it being `null` despite not being able to identify anywhere we don't pass that extra (we see it in our crash reporting but can't reproduce). The Activity in question is part of our open source code base, so I can link it here ([ErrorActivity.kt](https://github.com/getodk/collect/blob/master/errors/src/main/java/org/odk/collect/errors/ErrorActivity.kt)), but I'll provide an example of the setup here:

Activity:

```kotlin
class ErrorActivity : Activity() {
    companion object {
        const val EXTRA_ERRORS = "ERRORS"
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        
        val failures = intent.getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_ERRORS) as List<ErrorItem> // This line explodes due to EXTRA_ERRORS being null
       
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
 <activity android:name="my.code.ErrorActivity"/>
```

The Activity is pretty simple, no start modes and calling code doesn't use any flags. The only unusual thing is that it's often started from a notification:

```kotlin
val showDetailsIntent = Intent(application, ErrorActivity::class.java).apply {
    putExtra(ErrorActivity.EXTRA_ERRORS, results as Serializable)
}

return PendingIntent.getActivity(
    application,
    101,
    showDetailsIntent,
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
)
```

We can't find an example where `results` above can be `null` and I can't identify an Activity recreation scenario where the Intent extras get wiped, another Intent replaces the original passed to the Activity. As far as our tests and our own use of the app are concerned, this problem doesn't occur - we're only able to see it crash reports.

Does anyone know of a scenario that can cause an Activity with extras to "lose" them?

EDIT: In the example given, `ErrorItem` is a Kotlin `data` class that implements `Serializable`.

Comment: Java serialization is black magic. For data classes, Gson is 1000x times more reliable since you can pass extra as string, which is bulletproof

Comment: Why not make the result class implement Serializable instead of trying to cast it later

Comment: @return0 `ErrorItem` implements `Serializable`. I've edited the question so that's hopefully clearer.

Comment: ErrorItem already implements serializable so doing( results as Serializable ) is redundant. Also check if you're using R8 then add a keep rule for ErrorItem